# How do I use OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR instead of the usual Rails /public/data/file.txt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift, redhat

My current Rails app creates directories with files that need to be accessible in a browser as such `www.xyz.com/data/file.txt`. All I do now is write them out to `/public/data` within my controller. I'm trying to host my app on Openshift, but I have no idea how to go about implementing my app using their persistent storage variable.

PS: Giving the user some big long file path representing `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/data/file.txt` is not an option... It must remain `www.xyz.com/data/file.`txt

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a new Rails project on OpenShift and it comes with a default `public/` directory, and that's accessible directly on the browser. So just `$ mkdir public/data` and put your files there, then access files using yourapp-yourdomain.rhcloud.com/data/file.txt

Edit based on scalable requirement:

For scalable apps, the `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` is not a good solution, as it is not rsynced and won't be duplicated to the new gears. You can find some other solutions such as [MongoDB GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) and then create some route that searches and serves the files.

Comment: Hey Joao, thanks for the answer. That is what I was doing, but someone told me I should use the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR or the app won't be scalable. Is that true? And the other issue, is that a Git push will erase new files users create from the browser. But I've just used SFTP and avoided Git...

Comment: @esp4u you can't use the file system for this, check https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-scale-your-ruby-on-rails-application/ . So your best solution is probably to have your file storage handled by some database (which deals internally with scalability)